# HIDSharp and endpoints

Tags: c#, hid, libusbdotnet

i'm trying to connect with a skylanders portal using hidsharp and have had little success. I've managed to pull some data from it but for this to be useful i need to send commands over a usb endpoint. after a day of looking around, i've made no progress, do i need to use another library? I've attempted using the LibUSBDotNet NuGet Package. This was not able to find the device, i suspect this is as it is a HID device. Is there any way to send data over an interrupt endpoint in c#, for HID devices i mean, and not standard usb devices. I'm welcome to anser all questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't know, you didn't include any relevant code...

Comment: I'm just asking for instructions on how to send data over an interrupt endpoint using c#, LibUSBDotNet is the package i used but can't access the device as it uses the HID interface. If you still need the code i'll provide. I'm happy with a library that could do this though